# How can the author choose when to publish an article, whether the article gets a teaser or not?

Tags: nodes

Is there a possibility for the author/editor to decide - when publishing - whether the article (the content type) gets a teaser or not? 
This is important for the look of the article on the front page.

I thought so far that would have to be defined before in the content Type.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then this can be done by checking the `Promoted to Frontpage` box on the article.

You can then change your view to filter out nodes that have `Promoted to Frontpage` checked.

Comment: No, the author himself should decide whether this information article should be published independently of the publication on front page in full length or with a teaser. This is my mine only with different content types, right?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Community Documentation about [View modes](https://www.drupal.org/node/1577752), here is an intro about it (from that same page):

> How a node is displayed depends on the context in which it is viewed, such as the difference between full nodes and teasers. On the page for field display management there are extra settings under the label custom display settings. The settings consist of a check box list of all view modes available for nodes, marking which view modes should have customized display settings. In a standard Drupal installation only teaser is checked, resulting in two sub tabs on the manage display page – default and teaser. The sub tabs lead to separate settings for each view mode.

Some more details (from the same linked page):

- In Drupal 7, additional View modes can be added to entities using `hook_entity_info_alter()`.
- In Drupal 8, adding a custom view mode can be accomplished without code. To add one, expand Custom Display Settings on the Manage Display tab of a content type, then click Manage View Modes.

So if you'd only add 1 optional (text?) field to store such teaser, the author/editor could use that to optionally use such teaser, and by using "View nodes" you (as an admin) can decide how to dislay them.

Comment: Hi Pierre, I've tried it. There is no possibility for the Author to change Teaser/or not. Which Drupal Version do You mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to do this, you'll need to add a field or other setting to the content to indicate how the article is displayed. The [Custom Publishing Options](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_pub) module would be one way to add the option to the edit form. Alternately you could just use a field.

As Pierre suggested, a custom view mode will help with the next step. You might create a new view mode called 'full_or_teaser':

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info_alter().
*/
function mymodule_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
   $entity_info['node']['view modes']['full_or_teaser'] = array(
  'label' => t('Full or teaser'),
  'custom settings' => FALSE,
 );
}
```

That view mode can then be selected in your front page view.

Now you need to select full or teaser output depending on the setting for the node. There's a number of ways you could do that but [hook_entity_view_mode_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_mode_alter/7.x) looks like the best for this case:

```
function my module_entity_view_mode_alter(&$view_mode, $context) {
   if ($view_mode === 'full_or_teaser') {
       $node = $context['entity'];
       $view_mode = empty($node->myoption_full)? 'teaser': 'full';
   }
}
```